# C Pointer Casting

Tags: c, pointers, typecasting-operator

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
 {
  char *cp;
  short *sp;
  int *ip;
  short x[6];
  int i, y;
  y = 0x0102;
  for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) 
  {
    x[i] = y;
    y = y + 0x1010;
  }
  cp = (char*) x;
  printf("1) *cp = %x\n", *cp);
  sp = x;
  printf("2) *sp = %x\n", *sp);
  printf("3) cp[3] = %x\n", cp[3]);
  ip = (int*) x;
  ip = ip + 1;
  printf("A) *ip = %x\n", *ip);
  printf("B) cp[6] = %x\n", cp[6]);
  sp = sp + 5;
  printf("C) *sp = %x\n", *sp);
  *x = *cp + 2;
  printf("D) cp[1] = %x\n", cp[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

I do not understand how the short array is typecasted to a char, and what happens when the typecast happens. Could someone kindly help me out with this !!

Comment: It's not an array that is casted, but a pointer. `x` is the address of the `0`th element, basically it's `short*`

Comment: The behaviour is undefined because the program accesses a `short` object via a pointer to `int`, so absolutely anything can happen.

Comment: In addition to the invalid casts, `"%x"` is the wrong format for most values.

Comment: %x is used to print the output in hexadecimal format.

Comment: This program does produces a output. But I dont know how that output is obtained...

Comment: @SindujaPrakash You apparently misunderstood what Bo was trying to say.  Read the specifics about format specifier expectations in the [documentation for `printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf). You'll see that `%x` expects an `unsigned integer`, and you're essentially lying to `printf` by passing `char` values for that specifier instead. The only thing saving your runtime-bacon is [default argument promotions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Default_argument_promotions), which is promoting those values to `int`, still wrong, but at-least size-compatible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You declared a `short` array of 6 elements named `x`.

You assigned values into each of these elements. The initial values would be:

```
+------+--------+
| x[0] | 0x0102 |           
+------+--------+
| x[1] | 0x1112 |             
+------+--------+             
| x[2] | 0x2122 |             
+------+--------+             
| x[3] | 0x3132 |             
+------+--------+             
| x[4] | 0x4142 |             
+------+--------+             
| x[5] | 0x5152 |             
+------+--------+
```

I'm making a few assumptions here but modify them if that's not your case.

```
sizeof(char)  = 1 bytes
sizeof(short) = 2 bytes
sizeof(int)   = 4 bytes
Endianness    = little endian
```

So in memory, it would look like

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 11 | 10 | 9  | 8  | 7  | 6  | 5  | 4  | 3  | 2  | 1  | 0  |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 51 | 52 | 41 | 42 | 31 | 32 | 21 | 22 | 11 | 12 | 01 | 02 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| x[5]    | x[4]    | x[3]    | x[2]    | x[1]    | x[0]    |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

where the

- 1st row: the bytes numbers(used just for identification purposes
  here)
- 2nd row: the content at the memory in hexadecimal (each 2 characters in hexadecimal represent a byte)
- 3rd row: the index of the
  array `x`

You cast the base address of `x` and assign it to the `char` pointer `cp`. The `printf()` sees a character in `*x` whose size is `1` byte.

`x` pointed to byte 0 and so does `cp` but in the case of the latter, only `1` byte is considered as `sizeof(char)` is `1`.

The content at byte 0 happens to be `0x02`.

So,

```
cp = (char*) x;
printf("1) *cp = %x\n", *cp);
```

prints `2`.

`sp` is a `short` pointer, the same type as `x`. So `*sp` would print the same thing as `*x`. It will consider the first `2` bytes from the given address. `sp` points to byte `0`. So bytes `0` and `1` will be considered. Therefore, the value is `0x0102` which is printed by

```
sp = x;
printf("2) *sp = %x\n", *sp);
```

`cp` still points to byte `0`. `cp[3]` is effectively `*(cp+3)`. Since `cp` is a `char` pointer, `cp+3` will point to `0 + 3*sizeof(char)` which is `0 + 3*1` which in turn is byte `3`.

At byte `3`, we have `0x11` and only a single byte is considered as `sizeof(char)` is `1`.

So,

```
printf("3) cp[3] = %x\n", cp[3]);
```

will print `11`

In

```
ip = (int*) x;
ip = ip + 1;
printf("A) *ip = %x\n", *ip);
```

The integer pointer `ip` is assigned the base address of `x`.
Then `ip` is incremented by `1`. `ip` initially pointed to byte 0. Since `ip+1` will point to byte `0 + 1*sizeof(int)` which is `0 + 1*4` which in turn is byte 4.

So `ip` now points to byte 4. Since it is an integer pointer, 4 bytes are considered - namely bytes 4, 5, 6 & 7 the content of which is `31322122`.

`cp[6]` means `*(cp+6)`. `cp+6` points to byte 6 the content of which is `32`.

Hence,

```
printf("B) cp[6] = %x\n", cp[6]);
```

prints `32`.

```
sp = sp + 5;
printf("C) *sp = %x\n", *sp);
```

`sp` after adding `5` to it, now points to byte `0 + 5*sizeof(short)` which is `0 + 5*2` which in turn is byte 10 the content of which after considering 2 bytes (bytes 10 & 11) is `5152`.

```
*x = *cp + 2;
```

`*cp`'s value is `0x02`. 
`*cp + 2` is `0x02 + 0x02` = `0x04` = `0x0004`.
This value is assigned to the integer pointed to by `*x` (bytes 0 & 1).

So byte 0 is now `0x04` and byte 1 is now `0x00`.

`cp[1]` is `*(cp+1)`. `cp+1` points to byte 1 the content is now `0x00` which is printed when

```
printf("D) cp[1] = %x\n", cp[1]);
```

is done.

Comment: Thank You Very much. This is a perfect explanation and I understood it very well.

Comment: @SindujaPrakash Glad to help.